# Why can't lein repl find function?

Tags: debugging, clojure, leiningen

I'm using

```
[ics@steamboy util]$ lein version
Leiningen 2.5.1 on Java 1.7.0_91 OpenJDK Server VM
```

with Clojure 1.6

In `lein repl` I used to be able to call a function from within `repl`.

```
util.core=> (load-file "src/util/core.clj")
#'util.core/-main
util.core=> (bldg-sqft-test)
```

And execute a function from within the `repl`.

```
(defn ret-val-from-sos
  "Takes a value, a map key, an s-o-s, and returns first match."
  [in-val map-key-1 map-key-2 s-o-s]
  (doseq [x s-o-s]
    (println (str (first x)))))

(defn bldg-sqft-test
  [& args]
  (let [bldg-cols (fetch-csv-data "bldg_sqft_cols.csv")
        bldg-data (fetch-csv-data "Buildingsqft.csv")
        mapped-data (xform-sos-in bldg-data bldg-cols)
        my-bldg-sqft (ret-val-from-sos (str 70782) (keyword "Bill#") (keyword "Fin. Area") mapped-data)]
    my-bldg-sqft))
```

Debugging was easier, when I could examine variables in repl. As a workaround, I've converted a library to run with a main, but it's not as effective as `repl` debugging

What settings/configuration do I need to do call functions from within the repl?

Comment: You're getting a type cast exception when you run your function. Without knowing the other code involved, it's difficult to know exactly where the problem is.

Also, you should be able to use (require 'util.core) rather than (load-file) to load in a namespace.

Comment: The exception you're getting should be a question on its own, it has nothing to do with the repl.

Comment: I wasn't concerned with the error, as much as why I could not find the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `$ lein repl` a JVM instance is started and it loads all the namespaces in your classpath, so (load-file "example.clj") isn't necessary.

The correct sequence for what you're trying to do is:

```
$ lein repl
user=>(require 'util.core)
nil
user=>(in-ns 'my-ns.core)
nil
my-ns.core=>(bldg-sqft-test)
```

or

```
$ lein repl
user=>(require '[util.core :refer :all])
nil
user=>(bldg-sqft-test)
```

If you somehow need to load a external .clj file then `(load-file "external.clj")` will add the file to the classpath and then you can require the namespace as above.